# Highlight the numbers on Number line

Tags: color, highlighting, number

I would like to highlight the numbers with different colors like in first number line highlight the numbers from 0 to onwards, in second number line from 0 to onwards and in third number line highlight the all numbers. Thank you in advance

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
        \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{};
        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{
            \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1.5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{};
    \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{};
    \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "highlight in different colors", should all the highlighted numbers have different colors (one blue, one green, one red, etc) or should all the highlighted numbers have the same color (all blue for example)? And what should be the difference between the first and the second line (now they are both described as "highlight from 0 to onwards")? Maybe you can provide a (screenshot of a) sketch made in Paint or Powerpoint or something that can illustrate your desired output?

Comment: If it is just to output a certain range with the same color then something like `label=below:$\ifnum\x>0\color{blue}\fi\x$` might be sufficient.

Comment: @ Marijn I mean highlight by any single color, just like a strip.

Comment: Where do I add your suggestions? I mean how to modify my code?

Comment: Now you have a `\foreach` loop and inside that there is a `\node` statement and in there you have a `label=below:$\x$` option. You can substitute this option for the one I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: You want that each number highlight with a different colors or each numerical lines and numbers with a common color? For the last case `node[color=blue, ...., label-below:$\color{blue}{\x}$]` and the dots and numbers will in blue